# Error with Parse integrated with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When I'm trying to make a social media-like app using Parse, I get the following error when trying to go to the section to compose a "sweet". I'm trying to recreate what is in this video: (https://youtu.be/Q6kTw_cK3zY), and this is the error I am getting in the console output :

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cfdc65           __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107868bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cfd8a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x000000010611bb53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c45d50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
5   UIKit                               0x000000010687452b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
6   UIKit                               0x00000001066cc718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
7   UIKit                               0x00000001066ccd08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
8   UIKit                               0x00000001066ccf79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
9   UIKit                               0x00000001066cd40e -[UIViewController view] + 27
10  UIKit                               0x00000001066f2297 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
11  UIKit                               0x00000001066fe3bf -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
12  UIKit                               0x00000001066fef0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
13  UIKit                               0x0000000106849715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
14  UIKit                               0x000000010661ca2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058caec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058bf6d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058bf546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010582b886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010582ca3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
20  UIKit                               0x0000000106599626 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2140
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c31431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c272fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c26934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c26366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
25  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108c02a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
26  UIKit                               0x000000010659c900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
27  switter                             0x0000000104834767 main + 135
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010883d145 start + 1
29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please provide the code in the question, I am not going to watch a video to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't know which code to post, the SIGABRT error is highlighting my AppDelegate, should I post that?

Comment: Add an 'Exception' breakpoint to your code, re-run, and post the code where it stops, that would help.

Comment: Anyway, a crash on setValue:forKey, that looks like either the value or the key is nil, or the key doesn't correspond to any property. My bet.

Comment: Just add an 'Exception' breakpoint and find out. Don't think that will have something to do with Parse?